# Photos uploaded to Facebook Page via Graph API cannot be tagged on Facebook (website) by non admin users

Tags: facebook-graph-api, tagging, facebook-page

If I upload images to an album on my facebook PAGE (not profile) via facebooks website then other (non admin) users of that page can tag themselves in the photos. I have set that up in my page preferences.

"Posting Ability: People can add tags to photos by (PAGE NAME)"

However if I use the GRAPH API to upload the photos to an album on my facebook PAGE then only admin users can tag themselves.  I am sure this was not always the case.

Here is an example of two images in the same album, one can be tagged the other not!

**Image uploaded by the api:**
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=310796772303725&set=a.310794905637245.113595.170367249680012&type=3&theater

**Image uploaded via the facebook website:**
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=342651955784873&set=a.310794905637245.113595.170367249680012&type=3&theater

I would be very grateful if anyone could let me know why this is happening

Answer (score 1):

The solution is rather simple. The non-admin user must have Liked the page before they can tag someone. I Liked your page and I had the option to tag users in both images...